# Write value to peripheral and read same value from peripheral using core bluetooth ios

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am new in ios. I have gone through many method and came to know methods for read and write and implemented also but I cannot get the same value which is written by write method during read operation.I want message written in write method gets read during read method is it possible? When i am doing this i am getting blank message, no message is found. please help me to resolve.Thanks in advance.
 **code**

```
  /* Write data*/
        if WriteID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("D0F0-0B047047"))

            {
                var str:NSString = "heyaa..!!"
                data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: arrCharacteristics!.objectAtIndex(1) as CBCharacteristic , type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)

            }

 /* read data  */

            if ReadID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("C88-A248-C4AB1"))
            {
      peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(arrCharacteristics!.objectAtIndex(0) as CBCharacteristic)

     }

// did write method:
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didWriteValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {
        if characteristic.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("D0F0-0B047047"))

        {     
         var datastring = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(datastring)
        var alert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Message", message: datastring , delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

  }

    }
// did update method

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {
if characteristic.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("C88-A248-C4AB1""))
        {
            var str:NSString = NSString(data: characteristic.value, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("bbbbb--- \(str)")
            var alert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Message", message: str, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
            IBlblmessage!.text = str
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is `data` coming from in `didWriteValueForCharacteristic`?

Comment: from Write method **var str:NSString = "heyaa..!!"
                data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: arrCharacteristics!.objectAtIndex(1) as CBCharacteristic , type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)**   message is sent from here in string.

Comment: Your code doesn't show you writing and reading the same characteristic

Comment: I am  writing using "D0F0-0B047047" characteristics and i want to read data which is written over here using "C88-A248-C4AB1" characteristics.This is not possible?

Comment: Well, that is up to your BLE device - whether it makes the data written to one characteristic the value of a second characteristic

Comment: Yes hardware is programmed in such a way that written message is echoed back in read method but i am not getting it back. So is my way correct? or should I make any changes? Please suggest..

Comment: I am confused in this.Characteristics value in update method should be same as that of in did write method? characteristics value means data only??

Comment: You need to issue a read request for a characteristic before you can access its value. Writing won't set the value from a read point of view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63325/discussion-between-jalak-patel-and-paulw11).

Comment: If i give read request then how i will get the written value?
writing message will not write in characteristics value? which then i can call?
Do you have any information links regarding this that we have to read then write so that i can make out the flow.